# Prevent pre_get_posts filter on specific post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, customization, pre-get-posts, posts-where

I am running into one issue with **pre_get_post** filter.

Actually I have 4 post types. Post, Pages, Events, and Venue. I created one custom field called city for event and venue post type.

When creating custom field I have one option to select post type on which I want to display that custom field.

Now, on the front end part I added one filter on **pre_get_posts** and modified the main query to get all posts from specific city.

All things are working perfectly on events and venue listing and single page **but this filter also applies on post and pages as well.**

What I want is, **I want to remove the this filter from the post type which are not included   with that custom field.

I have tried with **$wp_query->query_vars['page_id']** this code but its not working any more.

Can any one help me to sort this our ?

FYI: My code looks like,

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'citywise_post_filter' );
function citywise_post_filter($query) {
    global $wp_query;
    if( isset( $_REQUEST['city_filter'] ) ){
        $city = $_REQUEST['city_filter'];
    }else{
        $city = $_SESSION['CURR_CITY'];
    }
    if ( !is_admin() ){
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_ct_selectbox_52f65ae267764' );
        $query->set( 'meta_value', $city );
        return;
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Aezaz

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Improve your conditional to include a check for post type being queried. It can be done via [`WP_Query::get`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods) method

So, where you have

```
if ( !is_admin() ){
    $query->set( 'meta_key', '_ct_selectbox_52f65ae267764' );
    $query->set( 'meta_value', $city );
    return;
}
```

replace with

```
if ( ! is_admin() && in_array ( $query->get('post_type'), array('event','venue') ) ) {
    $query->set( 'meta_key', '_ct_selectbox_52f65ae267764' );
    $query->set( 'meta_value', $city );
    return;
}
```

Also note that using this code, as **@offroff** noted in his answer, the filter will apply to all queries, the ones you triggered visiting a page (main query) and the ones being triggered via code, using `new WP_Query ($args)` (secondary queries).

To make the code filter not affect secondary queries, add a check for `$query->is_main_query()`, so the code becomes:

```
if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) return;

if ( in_array ( $query->get('post_type'), array('event','venue') ) ) {
    $query->set( 'meta_key', '_ct_selectbox_52f65ae267764' );
    $query->set( 'meta_value', $city );
    return;
}
```

Comment: Hi G.M. Thanks a lot. It works. only on single detail page. I can't able to get the current post type in category listing pages with **$query->get('post_type')** and get_post_type().

Comment: @ShaikhAezaz if in the category listing pages you want mix event, venue and standard post types, you probably can't do the trick using a `pre_get_post` filter. If the taxonomy shows only event and/or venue (and no other post types) you can use `is_tax('your_taxonomy')` to add another filter. Your aim is not very clear, maybe you can add more details in the question.

Comment: G.M. Yes I have other custom post types as well. And I just added city meta field to event and place but not in other posts. So I just want the filter that returns current post type .

Answer (score 4):

Wordpress has a great page about [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Along with `!is_admin()` you might wanna do `&& $query->is_main_query()`

In the top of your function you can do `if(is_single() || is_page()) {return;}` if you don't want the filter to apply on those pages.

Other conditionals u might be able to use is `is_post_type_archive('event') && is_post_type_archive('venue')`

Edit: Not sure I understand your problem but now I figured this might help you:

```
$query->set('post_type',array('event','venue'));
```

Comment: Hi offroff, I used the code that G.M. suggested and it works for me for category and taxonomy listing pages but now I can't able to get the post type on category and taxonomy listing pages. You know some solution with this ?

Comment: Maybe you have to set the post type, for example if(is_category()) {$query->set('post_type',array('event','venue')); }. It's hard to know how to solve your problem because we don't know what templates you're using.